# Erro em loop com laço for e a variável de controle do loop

Tags: programação-funcional

o erro que ta escrito é [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e o meu codigo é esse[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

alguem pode me ajudar a concertar esse bug?

obs a linguagem é a c

Comment: Opa, tudo bem? Recomendo que você lesse [este](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) post, sobre como fazer perguntas. E sobre o seu código: Como você está usando o laço for pra executar múltiplos prints, você tem que usar cerquilhas, para delimitar quais comando estão dentro e quais estão fora.

Answer (score 2):

O que falta são as chaves do laço `for`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
    for(int i = 0; i >= 1; i--){
        printf("%d garrafas de cerveja no muro\n", i);
        printf("bebo uma jogo no lixo\n");
        printf("%d garrafas de cerveja no muro\n", i - 1);
        if(i == 1){
            printf("1 garrafa de cerveja no muro\n")
            printf("bebo uma, jogo no lixo\n")
            printf("nenhuma garrafa de cerveja no muro\n")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: obg,acabei de testr e deu certo,vou prestar mais atençao nisso

Comment: e tambem leia o [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sobre como fazer uma pergunta correta, e tambem [esse outro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)